# Parent Role Name of Current User in SOQL

Tags: soql

Below query is giving me an error.What is the best way to get the Parent Role Name of current user.

```
list<UserRole> uRole = [Select u.ParentRoleId,u.ParentRoleId.Name, u.Name, u.Id
        From UserRole u where u.Id=:UserInfo.getUserRoleId()];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Force IDE schema view does not offer a "Foreign Key" (relationship) name for this which usually means that the relationship can't be crossed in a single query and that the Id will have to be used to perform a second query to get the data.